# LINKER ERROR: ld: library not found for -lPods (Trying to build .xcworkspace)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, linker-errors

It looks like the **linker fails** when it tries to run this command:

> Ld
>   ...Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-fnilwppptrsqymdbybvlohrlvbks/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PROJECTNAME.app/`PROJECTNAME

I tried to see if that path exists and it doesn't. It only exists up until:

> ...Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PROJECTNAME-fnilwppptrsqymdbybvlohrlvbks/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PROJECTNAME.app/

I am not sure how to get by this error?

(I'm trying to build the `.xcworkspace` so the issue is not with that.)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

- **Uninstall** the `App` from `Device` or `Simulator`.
- Make sure **close** all `Xcode` Projects. (`.xcworkspace` and `.xcproject`) (sometimes `.xcproject` still open)
- **Run** `pod install` and `pod update`
- **Open** the `.xcworkspace`
- **Clean** and **Build** your Project

After that you should be able to run normally.